# How do I update a git branch to match master?

Tags: git

Here's my problem. I have a branch off master, and i made some changes. A little later my partner reverted a change they had made because it was breaking something. When i ran `git fetch; git rebase master`master was fixed and everything was okay. But when I ran `git fetch; git rebase my_feature` the `my_feature` branch still had the same problems as before. How can i update the `my_feature` branch so that it takes into account the reverted commit? Thanks!

Comment: Was the commit reverted with `git revert` or `git reset`?

Comment: You could merge `master` into `my_feature`, if you don't mind bringing in everything else new along with the revert.

Comment: which branch are you on when you run `git rebase master` and `git rebase my_feature`?

Answer (score 16):

You first need to git fetch and git merge your master branch that is following the remote master branch. You can do this with `git checkout master` then `git pull origin master`. This will bring your master branch up to a place that is equilivant with the remote repository.

Then you will need to do the following to rebase your feature branch ontop of the new commits (a git revert is just another commit to a branch and should be treated the same as any other commit (with special concerns depending on the situation)):
`git checkout my_feature` then `git rebase master`.

This will rebase your feature branch ontop of the new local master branch which should be tracking the remote master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you branched `my_feature` off `master`, you have to do a `git rebase origin/master` while being on `my_feature` branch.

Answer (score 0):

If the master branch before had commits

```
(A) --> (B) --> (C) --> (D)
```

and the `my_feature` branch was based on `(D)`, which is now reverted so that `(C)` is the latest commit on master, then you can rebase `my_feature` onto `(C)` by running

```
git branch my_feature.orig my_feature                          # optional, delete this branch when satisfied
git rebase --onto master $SHA1_OF_COMMIT_D my_feature.
```